# How to customize button ok in Gtk.MessageDialog with CSS?

Tags: css, python-2.7, gtk3

My day's question is about apply CSS in default button in Gtk.MessageDialog. I tried a lot things without result.

The deal is to find th good id like buttons, or GTKbutton, or GtkMessageDialog.Button,......

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
    #demo_messagedialog_css.py
    from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk


class show_message_dlg:
    def __init__(self, message, type_message=Gtk.MessageType.INFO,stock_message=Gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_INFO, decorate=True):
        """
        This Function is used to show an message 
        error dialog when an error occurs.
        error_string - The error string that will be displayed on the dialog.
        ==>type_message=gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR for error message
        ==>type_message=gtk.MESSAGE_INFO for information message
        ==>type_message=gtk.MESSAGE_WARNING for  warning message
        GTK_WIN_POS_NONE


        GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER equivalent in python to Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER
        GTK_WIN_POS_MOUSE equivalent in python to Gtk.WindowPosition.MOUSE
        GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS equivalent in python to Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS
        GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ON_PARENT equivalent in python to Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ON_PARENT 
        """
        self.message = message
        self.message_dlg = Gtk.MessageDialog(type = type_message
                                , buttons = Gtk.ButtonsType.OK)
        self.message_dlg.set_decorated(decorate)
        self.message_dlg.set_markup(self.message)
        self.message_dlg.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ON_PARENT )
        style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

        css = """
            GtkMessageDialog
            { background:linear-gradient(to bottom, green, rgba(0,255,0,0));}
            #Buttons{ background-color: yellow}

            """
        style_provider.load_from_data(css)
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), 
        style_provider,     
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    def run(self):
        reponse = self.message_dlg.run()
        self.message_dlg.destroy()      
        return reponse  



if __name__ == "__main__":
    exemple = show_message_dlg(u"message in the box dialog ")
    exemple.run()
    Gtk.main()
```

after few white night and 150 black coffe I found a small part of answer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
#demo_messagedialog_css1.py
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk

class MyButtonClass(Gtk.Button):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyButton'
    def __init__(self, label):
        Gtk.Button.__init__(self, label)
        self.connect("clicked", self._clicked1)

    def _clicked1(self, button):
        print "button ok clicked"

class show_message_dlg:
    def __init__(self, message, type_message=Gtk.MessageType.INFO,stock_message=Gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_INFO, decorate=True):   
        self.message = message
        self.message_dlg = Gtk.MessageDialog(type = type_message)
        self.message_dlg.set_decorated(decorate)
        self.message_dlg.set_markup(self.message)
        self.message_dlg.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS )

        button_v = MyButtonClass('Ok button')
        self.message_dlg.add_action_widget(button_v, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        self.message_dlg.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        # line below necessary if button not defined like Gtk.MessageDialog(type = type_message, buttons = Gtk.ButtonsType.OK)
        self.message_dlg.show_all() 
        style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

        css = """
            GtkMessageDialog
            { background:linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, rgba(0,255,0,0));}

            MyButton {
                color: darkgrey;
                font: Comic Sans 20;} /* run OK for label font */

            MyButton GtkLabel{ background-color: blue} /* run OK for button background label*/
            /*MyButton GtkLabel{ background:linear-gradient(to right, yellow, blue,yellow,green,red,orange);}*/ /* run OK for button background label*/

            MyButton:active GtkLabel{ background-color: red;} /* do not run if state change */

            """
        style_provider.load_from_data(css)
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), 
        style_provider,     
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    def run(self):
        reponse = self.message_dlg.run()
        self.message_dlg.destroy()      
        return reponse  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exemple = show_message_dlg(u"message in the dialog box ")
    response = exemple.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print("OK button clicked and end")
    else:
        print("destroyed")
    Gtk.main()
```

please note special class button with class atribut **gtype_name** = 'MyButton' and CSS command adressed by MyButton {}

Now I don't understand why part below not OK when I click on button

```
MyButton:active GtkLabel{ background-color: red;}
```

Comment: Nobody has answer?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a solution for specific problem button

```
MyButton:active GtkLabel{ background: red;}
```

my exemple

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
#demo_messagedialog_css2.py
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk

class MyButtonClass(Gtk.Button):
    __gtype_name__ = 'MyButton'
    def __init__(self, label):
        Gtk.Button.__init__(self, label)
        self.connect("clicked", self._clicked1)

    def _clicked1(self, button):
        print "button ok clicked"

class show_message_dlg:
    def __init__(self, message, type_message=Gtk.MessageType.INFO,stock_message=Gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_INFO, decorate=True):   
        self.message = message
        self.message_dlg = Gtk.MessageDialog(type = type_message)
        self.message_dlg.set_decorated(decorate)
        self.message_dlg.set_markup(self.message)
        self.message_dlg.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER_ALWAYS )

        button_v = MyButtonClass('Ok button')
        self.message_dlg.add_action_widget(button_v, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        self.message_dlg.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        # line below necessary if button not defined like Gtk.MessageDialog(type = type_message, buttons = Gtk.ButtonsType.OK)
        self.message_dlg.show_all() 
        style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

        css = """
            GtkMessageDialog
            { background:linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, rgba(0,255,0,0));}
            MyButton {
                color: darkgrey;
                font: Comic Sans 20;} 
            MyButton:active { background: red;}
            MyButton GtkLabel{ background:linear-gradient(to right, yellow, blue,yellow,green,red,orange);}
            """
        style_provider.load_from_data(css)
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), 
        style_provider,     
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

    def run(self):
        reponse = self.message_dlg.run()
        self.message_dlg.destroy()      
        return reponse  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exemple = show_message_dlg(u"message in the dialog box ")
    response = exemple.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print("OK button clicked and end")
    else:
        print("destroyed")
    Gtk.main()
```